# mongo engine sequence field ( how to get next value )

Tags: django, mongoengine

I have a Document using mongoengine + mongodb as backend.
and i want to get the next available counter.

```
class Master(Document):
    mas_id = SequenceField(required=True, primary_key=True)
```

in document there are 3 records. is there any i can find the next counter which is 4.
count + 1 is not required here.

there are tables mongoengine.counters but cant access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query it via pymongo, alternatively if you haven't deleted anything then max `mas_id` + 1 is the next in the sequence, what / how is this required and what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have form where i have to pre populate text box with the next available id. and yes i have delete option also users can delete records as well.  In mongoengine.counters document next available counter exists. but i dont know how to access it.

Comment: Ah but if you display it, you can't guarantee it will be that value.  The way SequenceFields work mean that you have to use FindAndModify to get the next value and stop a race condition.  If you showed current max + 1, its not guaranteed to actually be that value another process / user could actually take that value when saving their document.